# Will events automatically be unbound after the element was destroyed?

Tags: jquery

What happens to the event when its element was destroyed? As far as I know, jQuery still has the event in its global "repository". In my case, a lot of elements are created, bound with an event and destroyed again...

Do I need to be scared of some memory problems after excessive use?

Comment: If you remove elements via jQuery methods (e.g., [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)) it removes associated event handlers and (jQuery) data too.

Comment: By the way, does it also do that for child elements?

Comment: For that you can use the `empty` method (http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: I had a similar question once, it turns out that jQuery deals with this internally when you replace content with its own functions. This even includes things like `.html`, etc. And yes, it does apply to child elements. You can also test this by using heapshot analysis on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you have a lot of event handlers attached to html elements then you should either remove them explicitly (by using jQuery methods like `remove` or `empty` instead of eg `detach` or 'regular' js) or change your event 'binding' strategy. What I mean by that is taking advantage of jQuery's event's delegation. This way you can seek out some common ancestor to your cluster of event-binded-elements and binding it to the event instead. A rule of thumb is always to minimize the number of event handlers.

Comment: @Dave but what and why? I'm certainly not infallible, but this is what I know. If you some arguments against it, let me hear it -- it's the only way to learn, right?

Comment: well, I'm referring to the main point: "you should either remove them explicitly...". I don't believe this is necessary. See the source here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L96 and here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L465 (empty is called by all content-changing functions)

Comment: I see what you mean now. My phrasing might have been a bit off here. What I meant was that one should be careful not to create to much of event handlers as that may lead to performance problems as feared by the OP. And true enough, looking at the code, it seems that unless told otherwise (eg. by using `detach` instead of `remove`) jQuery 'will prefer' to remove element's data as well. I'll edit my answer to reflect that better. Thanks for explaining.